# how to get request object without using @XmlRootElement for java objects in rest services

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, jackson-databind

I am trying to generate rest service using Apache CXF and Jackson data-binding. here I don't want to use **@XmlRootElement** annotation. when I try below code the request object coming like a null object.

here is my service interface

```
@POST
@Path("/getusers/")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<UserDetails> getusers(UserDetails userDetails) throws ServiceException;
```

here is my domain object

```
public class UserDetails implements Serializable{

private String userName;
private int userId;

public UserDetails(){

}
 //getters and setters...
}
```

The Json Object looks like

```
{
    "id" : "102",
    "username" : "scott"
}
```

And I am getting null-pointer exception for the request object

how do I access my request object
**Note:** here I am using Jackson Data-Binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON contains `username` while the member is called `userName`. Also, `id` and `userId` are different.

You have three options:

- Change the names of the `UserDetails` members to match the fields in the JSON object.
- Change the names of the JSON object to match the member names of `UserDetails`.
- Use `@JsonProperty` to configure the JSON object name to be bound to a `UserDetails` member.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the third option worked for me perfectly.

Comment: if I pass JSON Object like { "userName":"Sathish", "userId":"1"} I got the responce but actully I want to use like {"UserDetails":{ "userName":"Sathish", "userId":"1"}} when I use it i am getting Exception like Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "UserDetails" (class com.restServicesPOC.models.UserDetails), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "userName", "userId"])

Comment: yeah, but I am getting Exception when a request send from postman.
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "UserDetails" (class com.restServicesPOC.models.UserDetails), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "userName", "userId"])